# Procedure to install an Ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Unable to install ingress-nginx for kubernetes on Docker desktop

I was using the following in cmd line to install ingress nginx so far:

`$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/mandatory.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/provider/cloud-generic.yaml`

as shown in the web page: https://che.eclipse.org/running-eclipse-che-on-kubernetes-using-docker-desktop-for-mac-5d972ed511e1

I seems like the installatio procedure has changed. Can anyone let me know step by step instructions to install ingress-nginx? I coudnt install it by following the procedure described here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/deploy/index.md

Answer (score 1):

Installation via helm works perfectly for me. Assuming you have **[kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/)** binary installed and **configured to use for your k8s cluster** you can follow below steps one by one to achieve installation of nginx-ingress controller

1.Install helm binary (if doesn't exist)

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nurlanf/deployments-kubernetes/master/helm/get_helm.sh | bash
```

2.Install helm for your cluster (if not installed yet)

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nurlanf/deployments-kubernetes/master/helm/install.sh | bash
```

You should see output like

```
...
Waiting for tiller install...
Helm install complete
```

3.Then install nginx-ingress via helm

```
helm install stable/nginx-ingress --name nginx-ingress
```